# Settling for Australian PhD — terrible decision?

Tags: phd, ranking

I recently accepted a PhD offer from a top Australian university. There are many things I like about it: my supervisors are excited to work with me and the topic is almost exactly what I want to work on.

My educational background is quite strong however and I am aware that I am making the decision to stay in Australia partly for convenience (partner works here) and that I may have had a chance at universities more well known in my field. I am worried that I am jeopardising my career from the start by staying here.

I would be keen for some advice. Given that I like my topic and supervisors and that the university is ranked top 50 world wide, should I even be concerned? Or could I be making a big mistake?

Comment: Sounds like you have already established the trilemma in your question. I fear, how you weigh the three dimensions prestige vs fit vs convenience/partnership isn't a question we can help with, as it's subjective.

Comment: Venn Diagram Time!

Comment: I started writing a full answer but then decided against it. You've already accepted the offer. Have some faith in your decision! What's done is done. If you don't have the courage to face the consequences of your decisions for good or bad, you'll never get anywhere. If you renege now, you'll have a hell of a time explaining why you're reneging to your would-be supervisors. If you further take up a position in the same field but a different university ... remember that academia is a small world, with a very long memory. You might meet long-term consequences, e.g. if you return for a postdoc.

Comment: @user3727079 Yes, OP might be facing a form of shopper's remorse. :)

Comment: I have experienced the same feelings after every position I moved to. Nothing is forever, if you don't like it there, you'll be able to move. I did so from a "Top 500" (if  even) university.